# Add Together Object Values by Category and Date

Tags: javascript, object, key

So I am currently developing a Dynamic tool where I am selecting data using a Dropdown picker. Currently I want to select the data by Category and add all Values that include the same year and Category Together.

Here is an Example of my dataset.

```
var data:[{
           0:
             Age group: '6 years'
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Alberta'
             Sex:'Males'
             Value:'19632.0'
         },{
           1: 
             Age group: '7 years'
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Alberta'
             Sex:'Females'
             Value:'1030.0'
           },
          {
           2: 
             Age group: '5 years'
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Ontario'
             Sex:'Females'
             Value:'103.0'
           }
           {
           3: 
             Age group: '7 years'
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Ontario'
             Sex:'Females'
             Value:'1030.0'
           }]
```

I would like to add together all values, for whatever desired category select and sorted into year.

For example: If the user selects "Geography" add all values for each year and each specific category together to get their total.
So you have a single value per category for that year.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data=[{
             Age_group: '6 years',
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Alberta',
             Sex:'Males',
             Value:19632.0
         },{
             Age_group: '7 years',
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Alberta',
             Sex:'Females',
             Value:1030.0
           },
          {
             Age_group: '5 years',
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Ontario',
             Sex:'Females',
             Value:103.0
           },
           {
             Age_group: '7 years',
             Date:'2002',
             Geography:'Ontario',
             Sex:'Females',
             Value:1030.0
           }]
           
   function avg (data, group, group_value, value){
   var result = 0 
   var total = 0
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
      if(d[group] == group_value){
      result= result + d[value]
      total = total + 1
      }
    })
    return result/total
   }
   
   var avg_Geography = avg(data,'Geography','Ontario','Value')
   var avg_Age = avg(data,'Age_group','7 years','Value')
   
   console.log(avg_Geography)
   console.log(avg_Age)
```

1. Fix your array Object to proper format
2. Create Function with dynamic input
3. Run the function to get value